# svn: access to '<PATH>' forbidden, error MSB6006: "svn.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: svn, msbuild, teamcity, clickonce

I'm using TeamCity to build my solution and deploy it using ClickOnce. I'm getting the following error while I'm trying to build :

```
[Step 1/2] MSBuildScript\Test-TeamCity.proj.teamcity: Build target: DeployClickOnce (4s)
    [MSBuildScript\Test-TeamCity.proj.teamcity] GetProjects
    [MSBuildScript\Test-TeamCity.proj.teamcity] GetRevisionNumber (3s)
        [GetRevisionNumber] SvnInfo (3s)
            [SvnInfo] svn: access to '<SVN PATH>' forbidden
            [SvnInfo] G:\BuildAgentWorkDir\ecb07d678d26436f\MSBuildScript\Test-TeamCity.proj(66, 9): error MSB6006: "svn.exe" exited with code 1.
```

I have already checked the following things :

- Username/Password is correct and user has read/write access
- I've checked the path and case of SVN Path and it is correct
- The error occurs on calling svninfo to fetch the Revision Number, but this happens only on TeamCity server - with the same credentials svninfo works fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

SVN? Switch to Git or Mercurial :P (*joke*... not really change it as soon as you can).

Did you run the same script as TeamCity? I mean `Test-TeamCity.proj.teamcity`. Because TC run building through his own, special prepared project. 
Try running the same. If the error occur there is something in team city script. If not you are at the starting point - there is something wrong IN the agent.

Try login to the agent and connect to svn from there. Maybe svn version?